# Configuration class defined in @SpringApplicationConfiguration gets ignored in unit test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

In my application there are several tasks which have to get executed periodically in production but should not runx in my integration tests. (These classes are annotated with Spring's `@Scheduled` annotation.) I have two Spring Boot runner classes:

`Application`, defined as:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
    SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);
    ...
    }
```

and `ApplicationTest`, defined as:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class ApplicationTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationTest.class, args);
    }
}
```

My tests are annotated with the following annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(ApplicationTest.class)
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true)
```

I'm defining the class `ApplicationTest` as the `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` class, which should be used running the test. Unlike the `Application` class `ApplicationTest` is missing the required annotation to enable scheduling.

When I run the test using `mvn test` or even `mvn verify`, the annotation get's ignored, starting the application using the `Application` class and thus starting the scheduled tasks.

What am I missing?

Comment: are both `Application` and `ApplicationTest` in the same package by any chance? If so, classpath scanning... Having said that, I wouldn't do this but rather enable scheduling with a profile (you could enable the profile in the main method of your `Application` class to make that transparent.

Comment: Could you provide a example as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both classes are probably in the same component scanning unit so since your `Application` is a `@Configuration` class the `@EnableScheduling` is invoked anyway.

You have a couple of things you could do to fix this:

1. Create a `Profile` for the scheduling part and enable that only when you run the app
2. Idem but enable that if the `test` profile is not active and enable such profile in your test

Here is an example for 1, the advantage is that you don't have to change anything to your tests

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setAdditionalProfiles("application");
        SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);
        ...
    }

    @EnableScheduling
    @Profile("application") // or @Profile("!test") for instance
    static class ApplicationConfiguration {

    }
}
```

Your `ApplicationTest` can now go away.

(btw you don't need a `main` method for your `ApplicationTest` class, Spring Boot is not going to execute the main method of such class for a test: `SpringApplicationConfiguration` takes a list of "sources" that are used to build the context).